# Issue with copying file into HDFS using FLUME

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I have a file in local file system which I want to move in HDFS using FLUME.

```html
hduser@ubuntu:~$ ls -ltr /home/hduser/Desktop/flume_test_dir/
total 7060
-rwxrw-rw- 1 hduser hduser 7226791 Nov  6 10:31 airports.csv
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:54310//user/hduser/flume/spool5
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup          0 2015-11-07 00:20 hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/flume/spool5/FlumeData.1446884442571.tmp
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup     137560 2015-11-07 00:21 hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/flume/spool5/FlumeData.1446884464560.tmp
```

So my actual file size is **7226791**. After FLUME is getting executed it is creating two files of size **137560** and **0**.

So the problem is the full file is not getting copied into HDFS and also it is getting split-ed. I want to move it as a single file and want to move the full file. I am using the below configuration. What change may need to be done there?

```html
#Flume Configuration Starts
# Define a file channel called fileChannel on agent_slave_1
agent_slave_1.channels.fileChannel1_1.type = file 
# on Ubuntu FS
agent_slave_1.channels.fileChannel1_1.capacity = 200000
agent_slave_1.channels.fileChannel1_1.transactionCapacity = 1000
# Define a source for agent_slave_1
agent_slave_1.sources.source1_1.type = spooldir

# on Ubuntu FS
#Spooldir in my case is /home/hduser/Desktop/flume_test_dir
agent_slave_1.sources.source1_1.spoolDir = /home/hduser/Desktop/flume_test_dir/
agent_slave_1.sources.source1_1.fileHeader = false
agent_slave_1.sources.source1_1.fileSuffix = .COMPLETED
agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.type = hdfs

#Sink is /user/hduser/flume/spool5/ under hdfs
agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:54310//user/hduser/flume/spool5/
agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollSize = 268435456
agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.rollCount = 50000000
agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.writeFormat=Text

agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent_slave_1.sources.source1_1.channels = fileChannel1_1
agent_slave_1.sinks.hdfs-sink1_1.channel = fileChannel1_1

agent_slave_1.sinks =  hdfs-sink1_1
agent_slave_1.sources = source1_1
agent_slave_1.channels = fileChannel1_1
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is `capacity full` as I am seeing the message in console `capacity 1000 full, consider committing more frequently` please suggest